# WinForm C# "new Process" in infinite loop causing application to crash

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a requirement for which I need my block of code to run infinitely (The exit is an interrupt based on button click).

In each iteration, I am creating a Process, starting it, manipulating the output and then disposing the Process.

```
    void status()
    {
        do{
            Process test1 = new Process();
            test1.StartInfo.FileName = "doSomething"; // doSomething is executable
            test1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            test1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            test1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            test1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            test1.Start();
            string output = test1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            test1.WaitForExit();
            if (Regex.IsMatch(output, "DEVICE_READY", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            test1.Dispose();        
        }while(true);    
    }
```

The problem is the application is crashing with this code. If I just remove the loop, it works fine.

I checked while debugging, memory usage of the application keeps on increasing with each iteration of the loop, making the application crash at one point.

What I understood is Dispose() will release all the resources... so memory should not increase with each iteration.

Could someone please help to understand what is causing the memory usage increase?

Comment: Please provide the specific exception you get when you get the crash.

Comment: you can try adding `GC.SuppressFinalize(test1);` after disposing.

Comment: Dispose() does not clean memory, it only tells the garbage collector to 'pick it up' when he will start cleaning...

Comment: So what can I do to clean memory?

Comment: @user2407394 - Simple answer, you cannot.  Garbage collection in `C#` is managed by the [Garbage Collector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You could try reusing the process.  Declare the process outside the loop and set it in the loop, minimize your disparate allocations.

Answer (score 0):

What I do when I have to deal with hungry processes (eg. pictures manipulation) is to call the garbage collector explicitly.

This is not the cleanest way (costs a lot), but reasonnably used, it does the trick.

```
void status()
{
    // will be used to explicitly call the garbage collector
    const int COLLECT_EVERY_X_ITERATION = 10;

    // store the current loop number
    int currentIterationCount = 0;

    do
    {
        // increase current iteration count
        currentIterationCount++;

        using (Process test1 = new Process())
        {
            test1.StartInfo.FileName = "doSomething"; // doSomething is executable
            test1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            test1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            test1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            test1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            test1.Start();
            string output = test1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            test1.WaitForExit();
            if (Regex.IsMatch(output, "DEVICE_READY", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
        }

        // Explicitly call garbage collection every 10 iterations
        if (currentIterationCount % COLLECT_EVERY_X_ITERATION == 0)
            GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
    } while (true);
}
```